# Value allways returns null from localstorage (Ionic 3 + angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, local-storage, storage

I just added the storage plugin in my ionic 3 app (with angular 5).
The documentation is pretty straightforward... at least that's what I thought.

For some reason, I can store the value perfectly (also visible in debug tools), but I cannot read it back...

My code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

setItem(key: string, value: string | Object | number): Promise<void> {
    return this.storage.set(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

getItem(key: string): Promise<string> {
    return this.storage.get(key)
        .then((value: any) => {
            console.log('---------------------------------------');
            console.log(value);
            return value;
        });
}

removeItem(key: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.storage.remove(key);
}

clear(): Promise<void> {
    return this.storage.clear();
}
}
```

My module:

```
NgModule({
declarations: [
    ...
],
imports: [
    ...
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ...
],
exports: [
    ...
]
export class GlobalModule {
}
```

So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...?
Maybe a sidenote, because I don't know if it's relevant.
I already use SQLite plugin from ionic and it works fine. So now I'm trying to add localstorage to store simple datapairs...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Kind regards

Comment: Is the `console.log(value)` under `getItem()` empty??

Comment: Yes every time... And when I open the chrome debug tools, under application -> local storage, I can see the key with the correct value...

Comment: In your component, are you calling `getItem()` before calling `setItem()`?

Comment: No, That was my first thought to, that the writing wasn't done yet. But I even tried it when I restarted the app (so the variable was allready in the local storage from the previous run...). And still, the value was null

Answer (score 1):

`getItem(key: string): Promise<string>` returns a promise, but you already call `.then()` on it within the method. `return` does not work in `.then()` because it is an asynchronous method within a synchronous one. Either return the promise without `.then()`, or return nothing and do something with `.then()` in that method.

Comment: I don't believe that this is true, you can always return from a `then()`, utilize the return value by doing a `then()` again i.e. chaining them, for example here, he would do something like: `this.getItem(auth).then((tokenValue) => { ...})`

Comment: Normally the code is just one line return this.storage.get(key), I put the then in there to check the value... because without the "then()", the value is still null...